# Bash variable format

Tags: bash, shell, text, awk

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
uname=`awk 'NR>1{print $1}' foo.txt`
echo $uname
```

If I execute the command awk 'NR>1{print $1}' foo.txt by itself, I get the following format:

```
abc123
Apple
Test
```

When I save the command as a variable and echo it, the output becomes:

```
abc123 Apple Test
```

How would I go about making sure the output of $uname will be in the first output form listed above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply quote your variable as you ALWAYS should unless you have a specific purpose in mind by leaving it unquoted and fully understand all of the implications:

```
echo "$uname"
```

Btw you should use

```
var=$(cmd)
```

instead of the deprecated

```
var=`cmd`
```

Comment: Easy enough! It's been a minute, shaking off rust and still learning!

Comment: Just waiting for the time limit to let me click!